# Mocking Axios in React Hooks using react-hooks-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-hooks-testing-library

Trying to mock GET request to API but always get

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

even though I increased the timeout it still throws error.

**Hook**

```
export default function apiCaller() {
  const [rawApiData, setRawApiData] = useState({});
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');

  const callApi = async (inputValue) => {
    try {
      const apiData= await axios.get(
        `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?types=chart&symbols=${inputValue}&range=3m&token=lalaccf0`
      );
      setRawApiData(apiData);
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMsg(
        'Error occured!! ' +
          (Boolean(err.response) ? err.response.data : err.message)
      );
    }
  };

  return { rawApiData, callApi, errorMsg };
}
```

**Axios mock**

```
export default {
  get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: {} }),
};
```

**Test**

```
import { renderHook, act } from 'react-hooks-testing-library';
import apiCaller from '../components/stock-chart/stockApiCaller';
import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios');

it('should set error properly when api call is unsuccessfull because of bad data', async () => {

      axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { test: '123' } });
      const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => apiCaller());

      act(() => result.current.callApi('fb/tsla'));
      await waitForNextUpdate();

      expect(result.current.rawApiData.data.test)
        .toBe(123)
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: I get a failure because `"123"` isn't `123`, plus some warnings about the call to `act`, *not* a timeout.

Comment: I will edit the question to assert to '123'. Also i dont get the timeout issue that you are getting.

Comment: ...what? *You're* the one getting the timeout, that's what you've asked the question about; I'm *not* getting it.

Comment: Ohh. Sorry. My bad. Yeh i am getting the timeout thing..

Comment: I am reading so many things from everywhere that i got confused for a bit

Comment: My point is that currently you *haven't* provided a [mcve] - I cannot recreate the issue you've asked about.

Comment: got it. Let me edit the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the issue resolved. There is new way to write act() i.e. async act(). Please find below the updated version of test which works fine.

```
it('should set rawData properly when api call is successfull because of', async () => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { test: '123' } });
  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => apiCaller());
  await act(async () => {
    result.current.callApi('fb/tsla');
    await waitForNextUpdate();
  });
  expect(result.current.rawApiData.data.test).toBe('123');
});
```

Update react to 16.9.0-alpha.0

https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v16.9.0-alpha.0